# I am not getting the tweets from twitter

Tags: hadoop, twitter, hdfs, bigdata, flume

I try to stream tweets by Flume in the HDFS , I am not getting the tweets from twitter.The process is stopping at this point mentioned below.... !! Nothing beyond this step.

```
INFO instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup: Monitoried counter group for type: SINK, name: HDFS, registered successfully.
INFO instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup: Component type: SINK, name: HDFS started
```

My flume.conf file :

```
TwitterAgent.sources = Twitter
TwitterAgent.channels = MemChannel
TwitterAgent.sinks = HDFS

TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.type =       org.apache.flume.source.twitter.TwitterSource
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.channels = MemChannel
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.consumerKey = **************
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.consumerSecret =  *********
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.accessToken =************
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.accessTokenSecret = *********

TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.keywords = big data,cloud,hadoop,data analysis,hive,pig,hbase,flume,datawarehouse
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.channel = MemChannel
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.type = hdfs
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.path = hdfs://localhost:9000/Big
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.fileType = DataStream
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.writeFormat = Text
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.batchSize = 1000
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.rollSize = 0
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.rollCount = 10000

TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.type = memory
TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.capacity = 10000
TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.transactionCapacity = 100
```

Comment: any code you wish to share would be useful

Comment: Please, include this in the original post, by editing it and delete those comments

Comment: Ok please help me if you can.

Comment: Can you please check and post logs from <FLUMEDIR>/logs/flume.log file?

Answer (score 1):

try this code..

```css
TwitterAgent.sources = Twitter
TwitterAgent.channels = MemChannel
TwitterAgent.sinks = HDFS

TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.type = com.cloudera.flume.source.TwitterSource
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.channels = MemChannel
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.consumerKey = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.consumerSecret = xxxxxxxxxxxx
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.accessToken = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.accessTokenSecret = xxxxxxxxx

TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.keywords = big data,cloud,hadoop,data analysis,hive,pig,hbase,flume,datawarehouse

TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.channel = MemChannel
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.type = hdfs
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.path = hdfs://localhost:9000/Big
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.fileType = DataStream
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.writeFormat = Text
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.batchSize = 1000
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.rollSize = 0
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.rollCount = 10000
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.filePrefix = twitter_India-
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.round = true
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.roundValue = 2
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.roundUnit = minute

TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.type = memory
TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.capacity = 10000
TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.transactionCapacity = 100
```

Comment: It stoped in this step!! without establishing connection!
    INFO instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup: Component type: SINK, name: HDFS started

Comment: it worked pretty fine for me, you need to check the external jar required for this..

Answer (score 0):

In `flume.conf` file

```
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.path = hdfs://localhost:**9000**/Big
```

put your own Active localhost instade of 9000.

go to http://localhost:50070/ and you can see your active localhost. like in my case it is

```
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.path=hdfs://localhost:54310/user/flume/tweets
```